# Filter data on the query or with Java stream?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, java-stream, morphia

I have a Play 2.3.x Java application connected to a MongoDB database via Morphia.

I activated slow query profiling in MongoDB and saw that a query comes often. It looks like this :

```
"query": {
    "field1": null,
    "field2": true,
    "field3": "a061ee3f-c2be-477c-ad81-32f852b706b5",
    "$or": [
        {
            "field4.VAL.VALUE_1": "EXPECTED_VALUE_1",
            "field4.VAL.VALUE_2": "EXPECTED_VALUE_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

In its current state, there is no index so every time the query is executed the whole collection is scanned. I still have a few documents, but I anticipate the growth of the database.

So I was wondering what was the best solution :

1. Remove all the clauses above from the query, retrieve all results
   (paginated) and filter with Java `Stream API`
2. Keep the query as is and index the fields

If you see another solution, feel free to suggest it :)

Thanks.

Comment: You have a single object inside the `$or` array — what's the point of that?

Comment: You mark a point ! Because in another case I have several objects. But I have to handle the case when I only have one to avoid this useless `$or`

Answer (score -1):

Always perform everything that's possible (filtering, sorting etc.) nearest to the source of the data.

Why haven't you indexed the fields? That's what they're meant for.

Comment: Alright but I suppose indexes are not that magic and creating lots of them leads to poor write performances ? That's why I wanted to be sure before taking a decision over the other. I imagine such an index would look like this compound index : `{ "field1" : 1, "field2" : 1, "field3" : 1, "field4" : 1 }` ?

Comment: You should probably read some documentation. Now you're assuming a lot of things. Indexes are magical, they do incur a small write penalty, but I didn't say you should create *lots* of indexes. Reading all the data and filtering on Java side just says "I don't really know how to use my database". Besides, you should always measure the performance to see what's the best solution.

Comment: Depending on the specificity of your attribute values, it might be sufficient to index `field3`